# Is it okay to learn (device drivers with )kernel 2.6 today

Tags: linux, kernel

I am in process to learn device drivers. Most of the resources/books I found are based on 2.6 kernel. My question is, is it okay to learn device drivers (High level and low level bsp) based on kernel 2.6?
Will that be valuable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It will be (for the most part) exactly the same. There may be some slight differences, but that will be very easy to google and find the answer.

Here is a really good book/article on device drivers for linux: http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux/

Also, if you really want you can probably download a 2.6 kernel from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/ and either dual-boot or run a VM with that kernel.

Hope this helps!